# Refer to a xaml element in xaml.cs file in Windows 8.1 project

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

Hello I am currently learning Windows 8.1 development with Visual Studio 2015.
**How can I refer to a xaml element in a .xaml file from the associated .xaml.cs file**.
MainPage.xaml file:

```
<Page
x:Class="project.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:project"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

        <HubSection Width="600" x:Uid="Section1Header" Header="Map">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Button x:Name="mapButton" Content="Find my location"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
//...
```

MainPage.xaml.cs file:

```
namespace project
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            mapButton.Click += mapButton_Click;
        }
}
```

On `mapButton` I get the error : The name 'mapButton' doesn't exist in the actual context.
I thought `x:Name` was a way to give a name with wich I can access the xaml element from the .xaml.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to access the name of a button from a generated content. `mapButton` is not in the scope of the `Page` but in the scope of `HubSection`. What you really have to do, if you want to access the button element is to use the `VisualTreeHelper` to get the button at runtime.

Here is an example.

Helper function:

```
internal static void FindChildren<T>(List<T> results, DependencyObject startNode) where T : DependencyObject
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(startNode);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(startNode, i);
        if ((current.GetType()).Equals(typeof(T)) || (current.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
        {
            T asType = (T)current;
            results.Add(asType);
        }
        FindChildren<T>(results, current);
    }
}
```

Accessing the button:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (sender, e) =>
    {
        List<Button> results = new List<Button>();
        FindChildren(results, Hub);
        var mapButton = results.Find(item => item.Name.Equals("mapButton"));
        mapButton.Click += mapButton_Click;
    };
}

private void mapButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs arg)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Although if you really wanted to map a command to `Click`, you should consider doing it in the XAML through `binding`.

Comment: YES , YES , YES MISTER!!! I mean, your solution works fine, by the way there is a typo in the function sugnature: `DependencyObject tartNode`.